# msi installer - service isn't starting

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services

I've created an msi for a .net service (AqPlugins).  It builds without issue.

I've done an install using the msi on a server.  In the application log I see:

> Windows Installer reconfigured the
>   product. Product Name: AqPlugins.
>   Product Version: 1.0.0. Product
>   Language: 1033. Reconfiguration
>   success or error status: 0.

However, when I take a look at all the running services on the server I don't see AqPlugins.  Any idea what I could be doing wrong or where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the install you may also need to call InstallUtil e.g.

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil -i FullPathToExectuable
```

Comment: Thanks cmsjr, fantastic.  One question - where is the exe file going to be located?  I copied over the msi, and installed it, but I don't see the executable.

Comment: It depends on the MSI, by default an MSI will give you a screen to set the install location (if you didn;t mod it it should be Program Files\\(publisher)\SetUpProjectName), if your MSI does not include such a screen take a look at your setup project and see where it is being installed to. Failing that do a search for the executable on the file system.

Comment: It did have the screen, and I was looking in Program Files\\(publisher) etc.  That directory doesn't have any executable in it.  Its just a bunch of dll's and a .tlb file.

Comment: lol, I guess I should have asked what your output type was. I;ve never set it up this way myself, but InstallUtil should except the path to the dll that represents your primary output.